# How to make Nginx picking up nex SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, letsencrypt

I'm using Letsencrypt SSL certificates with Nginx (nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)).
From my understanding, Nginx needs to be restarted or, at least, have its configuration reloaded in order to pick the new certificate after its renewal.

However, after running

```
moby@c6867cdcfad4:/thermo# /etc/init.d/nginx reload
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx
```

The browser still shows the old certificate (I have tried different browsers with clean cache).

[image]

Even if the certificate has been renewed, as shown in the `Certbot` log

```
The following certs are not due for renewal yet:   
/etc/letsencrypt/live/thermo.com/fullchain.pem expires on 2019-08-26 (skipped)
 No renewals were attempted.
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Do your `nginx` config files have `ssl_certificate` pointing to this new certificate for this particular virtual host (assuming you're using virtual hosts)?

Comment: The `nginx` config points always to the same location.

Comment: You could try running `echo "" | openssl s_client -connect <server>:443 > capture.txt` then edit `capture.txt` to just leave the certificate before viewing that with `openssl x509 -noout -startdate -in capture.txt`.  OpenSSL will show the certificate sent by the server without any caching or the likes, so you can narrow down where the problem is likely to be.

Comment: You do not mention which operating system you are using, nor how `nginx` was installed so we are unable to reference the contents of `/etc/init.d/nginx`.  What does `/etc/init.d/nginx reload` actually do on your system?  Also, a reload should continue using old connections which would be using the original configuration until they are finished, make sure you are testing with a fresh connection.

Comment: I'm actually using Ubuntu on Docker and that seems to be causing the issue. Since the certificates are actually symlinked and symlinks don't work easily with Docker. I will run additional tests asap.  Thanks